# Compiler for Dog programming language

Tags: interpreter, dog

I recently came across a new programming language - "*The Dog programming language*"
I was searching for a compiler for this language.

I found [an article about the Dog language](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DOG).

I found a [Dog compiler written in the Perl language](http://viewsourcecode.org/code/perl/dog.txt) but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did find the pearl implementation for the dog compiler but m unsure how to use it<br>I tried using online pearl compilers line Ideone but no success
<br>

Comment: Near the top of that Perl script is: `"Usage: dog.pl program.dog\n"`.  So I'm guessing you would use that Perl script by saving it as `dog.pl` and invoking it on the command line as described.  `program.dog` would contain your DOG code.

Comment: Thanks
do I need to install pearl compiler first
if yes then what steps after installing the compiler

Comment: If you don't have a Perl interpreter then you'll need one, yes.

Comment: If you need the exact steps, these might vary depending on your OS. For example, if you are using Linux and have perl installed, it is as simple as downloading the script as a text file (and naming it anything you want), running `chmod +x name` (where `name` is the name of the compiler you just downloaded) and then running `./name dogsourcefile` (where `dogsourcefile` is the file containing your DOG code. **You do not need to name it dog.pl**)

Comment: It's Perl, not Pearl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to use the Perl DOG compiler

### Windows

First, install perl and make sure it is in your path:

Download it here: http://www.perl.org/get.html

You can use strawberry perl (possibly the other one too).

Then, download the compiler from http://viewsourcecode.org/code/perl/dog.txt and save it as dog.txt
(you can actually name it whatever you want but these instructions assume you named it dog.txt).

Make a DOG source code file. Let's assume it is called helloworld.dog.

Here's some code you can put into helloworld.dog:

```
bark "Hello world!\n"
```

Run it in a terminal (command prompt):

`perl dog.txt helloworld.dog`

### Linux/Mac/Unix

Download the compiler:

`wget http://viewsourcecode.org/code/perl/dog.txt`

Make it executable:

`chmod +x dog.txt`

Make a DOG source code file. Let's assume it is called helloworld.dog.

Here's some code you can put into helloworld.dog:

```
bark "Hello world!\n"
```

Run it:

`./dog.txt helloworld.dog`